Array signal processing: How to retrieve the snapshot information from Radar data cube
In DOA estimation we require a snapshot of data in time or frequency domain to perform the estimation. So how can we retrieve this information from the conventional radar data cube especially in the case of moving targets. Is this data retrieved over multiple scans or within the single radar data cube?

What do you think a “snapshot” means?

@Baddioes, I am also not sure what does 'snapshot' means in the context of radar. If I have a dataset with say 4000 pulses across 1 range gate then does that imply I have 4000 snapshots?

Yes, typically a snapshot refers to a measurement in slow time. So, it would be all samples in range and across the array for a given pulse.

@Baddioes you are right... That's what exactly snapshot means. So while performing the range and doppler FFT with this data set we get over multiple pulses we perform some sort of detection methods to find out the range and doppler of the targets. My doubt how to use this frequency domain data for the DOA estimation especially if the target is moving.

@Ananya, That's what I think of snapshots
